# using slick-carousel with typescript

Tags: typescript, slick.js, typescript-typings

Im new to typescript and im trying to get the a hang on the concept of how modules/packages works in typescript..

I am currently in the need of using slick-carousel to create a simple image slider.

However.. I have managed to install jquery.. but I dont quite get how to get slick to work with typescript.

So far I have used npm typings to install my packages.

So I just ran `typings install slick-carousel`.. and the definition-file showed up fine..
however.. the definition-file contains no declaration only interfaces..
So I cant really "import" slick-carousel into the file where I need to use it (I might be wrong).. so I guess that the package is supposed to extend the already existing jquery import in some why..

However.. If I do this:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

class Splash {
    init() {
        $.slick();
    }
}
```

then

```
$.slick();
```

cant be resolved..

so.. how do you "import" a package that only extends a pre-existing package like jquery?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using an AMD module loader (example [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)) would ensure your code only runs once all external modules, and their dependencies, have been loaded.

Here is an example using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) with a [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim):

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <title>jQuery++Slick+RequireJS Sample Page</title>
    <script data-main="app" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.2/require.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>jQuery++Slick+RequireJS Sample Page</h1>
    <p>Look at source or inspect the DOM to see how it works.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.js (after compiled from app.ts)**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: ".",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"
        "slick": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        }
        'slick': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '$.fn.slick'
        }
    }
});

requirejs(["jquery", "slick"], function($) {

    // Code within this function will only execute
    // once jQuery and Slick have been loaded.
    //
    // The configuration above ensures jQuery will always 
    // be loaded before slick.

    $.slick();

});
```

The [RequireJS documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) has a whole section on [how to use with jQuery](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html)

Comment: Why do you prefer require.js over the standard TypeScript imports? From a technical perspective, the import statement even compiles to a require.js import if you set the compatibility level to ES5.

Comment: My example was meant to show how to ensure dependencies have loaded before trying to use them. You are correct in that TypeScript will compile to AMD modules (require.js is an AMD module loader) if you  compile with the 'module' flag set to 'amd'. Starting with ES6 you will be able to load modules natively (without any type of module loader), at that point I would certainly use the native module loading capabilities. It's not that I favor require.js its just that using a module loader gives you more browser coverage. Hopefully that answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to declare $ . you can use `declare var $: any;`

```
declare var $: any;
class Splash {
    init() {
        $.slick();
    }
}
```

It won't give you error anymore :).

Answer (score 0):

1. install `jquery`
2. install `slick-carousel`
3. install `@typings\slick-carousel`
4. Add `slick.css` from the `node_modules`
5. optional: Add slick-theme.css.

At the top of the TS file add these 2 imports:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'slick-carousel';
```

Then use it like below:

```
$('.your-class').slick()
```